# Extending a field isomorphism to a field embedding of a bigger field

Tags: field-theory

Let $E$ and $F$ be two fields and let $f:E \longrightarrow F$ be a field isomorphism. Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field containing both $E$ and $F$. Is it possible to extend $f$ to a field embedding $\tilde{f}: \Omega \longrightarrow \Omega$?

I tried to apply Zorn's Lemma to the set

$$\{(M,f_M): E \subseteq M \subseteq \Omega \text{ is a field and } f_M : M \longrightarrow \Omega \text{ is a field embedding extending } f\}$$

with the following partial order relation

$$(M_1,f_{M_1}) \le (M_2,f_{M_2}) \Longleftrightarrow M_1 \subseteq M_2 \text{ and } f_{M_2} \text{ restricted to } M_1 \text{ equals } f_{M_1}.$$
The assumptions are satisfied but the maximal element could still have a domain strictly smaller than $\Omega$ and I don't know how (and if it is possible) to disprove that.

Is there a way to do it or is there a proof without using Zorn's lemma?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Assume $(M, f)$ is maximal and let $x\in \Omega\setminus M$, then if you succeed to extend $f$ to $M(x)$, then you're done.

Comment: @Berci I tried and it is not too difficult to extend $f$ in a suitable way. Problem is I don't know how to guarantee that $f:M \longrightarrow \Omega$ is not surjective. If this is the case I cannot extend $f$ to a field embedding onto $\Omega$. I'm stuck there

Comment: Hmm.. I guess that might indeed occur, e.g. with $\Omega=\overline{\Bbb Q(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)}$.. Then, probably first prove the case when $\Omega=\bar E$, and then try to extend it for the general case $\bar E\subseteq\Omega$ (hopefully in a trivial way can work)...

Comment: I will try your idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be true. Take $F=\Omega$ to be an algebraically closed field which is isomorphic to a proper subfield $E$ (i.e. has infinite transcendence degree over its prime field). Let $f:E\to F$ be such an isomorphism. Then it is not possible to extend $f$ to a homomorphism $\Omega\to\Omega$.